# Use of the article before team sports

Tags: articles

**Team sports** are considered as team building activities to keep an individual fit and healthy. While some people think that **the team sports** help in building a good personality and health.

Sports are considered as the personality building activities that will keep a person healthy and fit. The sports are very important to keep yourself healthy, happy, and cheerful.

Just want to know why the use of **the** before team sports/sports is wrong here. Apologies if this is a silly question.

Comment: It is not a silly question, but in my opinion it is not suitable for a site for "linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts" ([tour]). There is a sister site ([ell.se]) where questions of this sort are more appropriate, and in the case of the use of the articles in English, have probably been asked and answered before.

Comment: Why do you think it's "wrong"? Assuming a previous sentence already introduced a specific list of sports, then the definite article is fine, although it would probably be more natural to say *these* instead. However, more context is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The definite article is used when speaking of a specific item or items. The only way I can see "the team sports" working is if students (for example) must choose from a list of sports including some team sports. It then makes sense to say that the team sports, meaning the team sports on the list, help in building a good personality etc.

Similar considerations apply when speaking more widely of sports.